# Combine queues for async io with auto enqueue in tensorflow

Tags: queue, tensorflow, pipeline

I have multiple csv files which contain features. One feature is the filename of an image. I want to read the csv files line by line, push a path to the corresponding image into a new queue. Both queues should be processed in parallel.

[image: flow]

```
csv_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(10, tf.string)
csv_init = csv_queue.enqueue_many(['sample1.csv','sample2.csv','sample3.csv'])

path, label = read_label(csv_queue)

image_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(100, tf.string)
image_init = image_queue.enqueue(path)
_, image = read_image(image_queue)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    csv_init.run()
    image_init.run()

    print(sess.run([key, label, path])) # works
    print(sess.run(image)) # works

    print(sess.run([key, label, path])) # works
    print(sess.run(image)) # will deadlock unlike I do iq_init.run()
```

Implementation of helper functions (e.g. `read_csv`) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/440f3cf494e43e5a943f7546184ea738)

**Can I "hide" the call to `iq_init.run()` behind `sess.run(image)` to avoid deadlock and allow batching?**

Comment: Do you have to use two queues, one reading csv files and another one reading images? In your case, is it difficult to put all csv files into one?

Comment: @Seven Yes, this specific case may be a bit "artificial" but I think it may appear in some other context where you might want to push async objects from one queue to another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filenames = ['./cs_disp_train.txt', './cs_limg_train.txt']
txt_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
# txt_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(10, tf.string)
# init_txt_queue = txt_queue.enqueue_many(filenames)

enqueue_ops = []
image_queues = tf.FIFOQueue(100, tf.string)

num_reader = len(filenames)
for i in range(num_reader):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, buffer = reader.read(txt_queue)
    enqueue_ops.append(image_queues.enqueue(buffer))

tf.train.queue_runner.add_queue_runner(
    tf.train.queue_runner.QueueRunner(image_queues, enqueue_ops))

y = image_queues.dequeue()

sess = tf.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

# sess.run(init_txt_queue)

print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])
print sess.run([y])

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

For example, I have two files, 'cs_disp_train.txt' and 'cs_limg_train.txt', one is for depth images' file address, another is for corresponding color images' address. The code creates two FIFOQueues, one reading these two files, another reading all file names.

I am using [tf.train.QueueRunner](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#QueueRunner) too. But I am not sure I understantd it. I got inspiration from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py#L407), although it reads TFRecords files. Hope this could help you.

Comment: Sorry I edited the code a little. I use tf.train.string_input_producer for the first queue as FIFOQueue will be empty. tf.train.string_input_producer also returns a queue and it will not block.

Answer (score 0):

The deadlock arises on the second call to `sess.run()` because the `image_queue` is empty, and the [`reader.read()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#ReaderBase.read) operation (which produces `key` and `buffer`) will block until something is added to the queue. In TensorFlow, this is typically achieved by creating a [`tf.train.QueueRunner`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#QueueRunner), which defines a set of ops that can be run in a background thread to keep moving elements into the queue. For more details see the [tutorial on threading and queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html#threading-and-queues) in TensorFlow.

Comment: How does a code fix look like? What about the other questions?